# Why when using sort in redux state my component is not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

I have to sort an array of objects in ascending or descending order and i'm having trouble. My redux state is updating in redux dev tools and all works correctly but it doesn't show my changes on the component, it doesn't re-render.

Functions:

```js
const sortAsc = () => {
    const sortAscending = productsFiltered.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    console.log(sortAscending);
    dispatch(sortProducts(sortAscending));
  };
  const sortDesc = () => {
    const sortDescending = productsFiltered.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price).reverse();
    console.log(sortDescending);
    dispatch(sortProducts(sortDescending));
  };


  <button onClick={sortAsc}>sortAsc</button>
  <button onClick={sortDesc}>sortDesc</button>
```

Action:

```js
export const sortProducts = (products) => {
  return {
    type: ActionTypes.SORT_PRODUCTS,
    payload: products,
  };
};
```

Reducer:

```js
export const FilterCategoryReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.FILTER_CATEGORY:
      return { ...state, products: action.payload };
    case ActionTypes.SORT_PRODUCTS:
      return { products: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: `sort()` mutates the array, it doesn't return a new one. Also no need for `reverse()` just invert the subtraction `.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);`

Comment: I don't use Redux, but if it's like React with state, then the comparing is only shallow, IOW:  the array reference hasn't changed, so no update is detected.  As such you probably want to clone the array. eg.  `dispatch(sortProducts([...sortDescending]));`  ps, this cloning is also shallow, so it's not as big overhead as you might think..

Comment: thanks both, it works now with [...sortDescending]